# Is it possible to get the number of likes on a Facebook status without an access token?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I got this on the status:

```
{
    id: "100006579168423_1524160864479871",
    from: {
        id: "100006579168423",
        name: "Terry Xu",
        broadcast_name: "Terry X."
    },
    message: "test again #terryxu",
    privacy: {
        value: ""
    },
    place: {
        id: "X",
        name: "X",
        location: {
            city: "X",
            country: "X",
            latitude: X,
            longitude: X,
            street: "X",
            zip: "X"
        }
    },
    type: "status",
    created_time: "2014-08-01T01:33:31+0000",
    updated_time: "2014-08-01T01:33:31+0000",
    network: "facebook",
    facebook_id: "100006579168423_1524160864479871",
    kind: "status",
    order_id: "100006579168423_1524160864479871",
    entity_id: "100006579168423_1524160864479871",
    score: "100006579168423_1524160864479871",
    queued_at: 1406857103686,
    timeline_id: "86a7a49e-191c-11e4-91cf-0a3ce06e3fe5"
}
```

But shares and likes are not among them. Is it possible to get the number of likes on a Facebook status without an access token?

Comment: how did you get it? or did find any way ?